# Custom loss function in Keras that penalizes output from intermediate layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer, loss-function

Imagine I have a convolutional neural network to classify MNIST digits, such as this Keras [example](https://keras.io/examples/vision/mnist_convnet/). This is purely for experimentation so I don't have a clear reason or justification as to why I'm doing this, but let's say I would like to regularize or penalize the output of an intermediate layer. I realize that the visualization below does not correspond to the MNIST CNN example and instead just has several fully connected layers. However, to help visualize what I mean let's say I want to impose a penalty on the node values in layer 4 (either pre or post activation is fine with me).
[image]
In addition to having a categorical cross entropy loss term which is typical for multi-class classification, I would like to add another term to the loss function that minimizes the squared sum of the output at a given layer. This is somewhat similar in concept to l2 regularization, except that l2 regularization is penalizing the squared sum of all weights in the network. Instead, I am purely interested in the values of a given layer (e.g. layer 4) and not all the weights in the network.

I realize that this requires writing a custom loss function using keras backend to combine categorical crossentropy and the penalty term, but I am not sure how to use an intermediate layer for the penalty term in the loss function. I would greatly appreciate help on how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: which tool did you use to make this image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, what you are interested in is regularization and in Keras there are two different kinds of built-in regularization approach available for most of the layers (e.g. `Dense`, `Conv1D`, `Conv2D`, etc.):

- **Weight regularization**, which penalizes the *weights* of a layer. Usually, you can use `kernel_regularizer` and `bias_regularizer` arguments when constructing a layer to enable it. For example:

  ```
   l1_l2 = tf.keras.regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1.0, l2=0.01)
   x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(..., kernel_regularizer=l1_l2, bias_regularizer=l1_l2)
  ```
- **Activity regularization**, which penalizes the *output (i.e. activation)* of a layer. To enable this, you can use `activity_regularizer` argument when constructing a layer:

  ```
   l1_l2 = tf.keras.regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1.0, l2=0.01)
   x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(..., activity_regularizer=l1_l2)
  ```

  Note that you can set activity regularization through `activity_regularizer` argument **for all the layers, even custom layers.**

In both cases, the penalties are summed into the model's loss function, and the result would be the final loss value which would be optimized by the optimizer during training.

Further, besides the built-in regularization methods (i.e. L1 and L2), you can define your own custom regularizer method (see [Developing new regularizers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/Regularizer#developing_new_regularizers_2)). As always, the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/Regularizer) provides additional information which might be helpful as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! The activity regularizer seems to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4):

Just specify the hidden layer as an additional output. As `tf.keras.Model`s can have multiple outputs, this is totally allowed. Then define your custom loss using both values.

Extending your example:

```
input = tf.keras.Input(...)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(input)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(x1)
x3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(x2)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[x3, x2])
```

for the custom loss function I think it's something like this:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  x2, x3 = y_pred
  label = y_true # you might need to provide a dummy var for x2
  return f1(x2) + f2(y_pred, x3) # whatever you want to do with f1, f2
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this idea. This definitely seems to help. Would I specify separate loss functions for x3 and x2, or would I combine that into one loss function? For x3 I would want minimize categorical cross entropy between the original and predicted labels (y) and for x2 I would just want to minimize the squared sum. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer. It's one loss function, because otherwise the model doesn't know how to combine them (add, multiply, ...?). I didn't check if this code runs to be honest, but I hope this can at least get you started! Conceptually it is for sure correct, but you might need to do some degging to get tensorflow to work. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. You brought up a great point and conceptually this makes a lot of sense. I'll play around with this.

Comment: @FrederikBode It's a nice concept. Thanks. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to add loss based on input or calculations at a given layer is to use [the  add_loss() API](https://keras.io/api/losses/#the-addloss-api).  If you are already creating a custom layer, the custom loss can be added directly to the layer.  Or a custom layer can be created that simply takes the input, calculates and adds the loss, and then passes the unchanged input along to the next layer.

Here is the code taken directly from the documentation (in case the link is ever broken):

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

class MyActivityRegularizer(Layer):
  """Layer that creates an activity sparsity regularization loss."""

  def __init__(self, rate=1e-2):
    super(MyActivityRegularizer, self).__init__()
    self.rate = rate

  def call(self, inputs):
    # We use `add_loss` to create a regularization loss
    # that depends on the inputs.
    self.add_loss(self.rate * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(inputs)))
    return inputs
```